# Delete last character entered in input - Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, onkeyup

i have the following input:

```
<input id="myInput" type='text' onkeyup="validate(this)" />
```

And in my .js file I have:

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    console.log(e.key);

});

function validate(characters) {
    console.log(characters.value);
}
```

My question is: can I delete the `e.key` corresponding to the last character typed.

> Note:
>
> Deleting the last character of characters is not a solution, since the
>   character can be placed in any position.

Comment: when do you say it's last?

Comment: Save the value of the input BEFORE every key press.  Then it is possible to revert the last key by restoring the inputs value.

Comment: Be aware that changes can be done in bulk, like copy/paste, drag/drop, and can be the result of deletions also. `keyup` may not trigger for all of these changes.

Comment: Also take into consideration the user-experience. If you immediately delete a character that is being typed, this is not intuitive to the user. They may even think their keyboard is not functioning correctly. Better is to leave the input as entered, and give visual clues that the input does not pass validation. And there are standard HTML attributes to serve this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it based on the caret's position

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')

input.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  const position = e.target.selectionStart
  input.value = input.value.substring(0, position-1) + input.value.substring(position+1)
})
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```

Or you could track changes

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')

let previousValue = input.value
input.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  // if it matches your condition
  input.value = previousValue

  // reassign so that it works again next time
  previousValue = input.value
})
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```

Of course, you'd want to add conditions to these otherwise you can't type at all in your input. And check which keys are pressed because some don't add characters (or even remove some). You might want to look at the `"change"` event instead of the `"keyup"`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `keydown` event listener and prevent default behavior on some specific cases:

```
input.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'd') {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

This will prevent 'd' from input

Comment: What a smart answer, thank to @ivan-frolov. `keydown` happens before `keyup` and inputs will changes with keyup, so you can simply prevent change with `e.preventDefault()`.